# window.open conflict with WordPress page load

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to show the preview of some content in a new tab on a button click . I am using an Ajax on button click to prepare content. When the Ajax returns the response, the content is passed to a new tab as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,                        
    data: preview_data,
    success:function(data){
        if( data ){
            var url = localized_variables.admin_url+'&preview=1'; // This is the url of WordPress admin page with a parameter `preview` just for visual purpose
            var w = window.open(url, 'Preview');
            $(w.document.body).html(data);
        }
    }
});
```

The `url` field has the url of WordPress admin page with a parameter `preview` just for visual purpose

When the new tab is opened, rather than displaying the passed content, the page displays wordpress content.

If I am not pass `url` in `window.open`, then the content will be displayed in a new tab with `about:blank` in url field. But I want the URL to be same as the page URL with parameter added.

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo. `localized_variables.admin_url+'&preview=1'`

Comment: The thing is Instead of displaying the content passed via jQuery, the page loads the content of wordPress page in the URL

Comment: So that is then the `data` that is not what you expect

Comment: Yea. The page shows WordPress data rather than passed data

Comment: I would guess the data is NOT what you expect so you need to process it or pass different data from ajaxurl

Comment: The data passed is the correct one. My issue is that the URL already have content setup to show. The new URL( which is the old url + a parameter ), which is used only to give a meaningful URL, does load the page. But I want the page load to blocked and fill the page with jQuery Data

Comment: Ah, then have the server not fill the page if preview is 1

Comment: I tried that. I have written code not to fill which is working. But the jQuery data is not filled

Comment: Then the page has no body

Comment: The page had blank head and body tags

Comment: Looks like the content from jQuery is replaced by WordPress page content. I think I have a hint here. Thanks for the direction

Comment: Timing issue? Use setTimeout and hide when loading, show after

Comment: That's working. Thanks for the helping hand. But Is this a proper solution ? Can I move ahead with it or Should I really find the issue ? The thing is I cannot find a place to tell the server not to fill the page. I am using WordPress and every hooks I use to disable content doesn't work

Comment: I am sorry, I have no affinity with WP